# react native TypeError: ... is not a function. (In '...)', '....' is undefined) error, pass data between screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to make a simple app and book part is one of the part of this app . I have only 4 components/screens that using book object so I want to use prop passing data between screens. but I got an error "TypeError: onAddBook is not a function. (In 'onAddBook(text)', 'onAddBook' is undefined)" when I press addbook button below. The first component/screeen is

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { useReducer } from "react";
import AddBook from "./AddBook";
import BookList from "./BookList";
const MainBook = () => {
  const [books, dispatch] = useReducer(booksReducer, initialBooks);
  function handleAddBook(text) {
    dispatch({
      type: "added",
      id: nextId++,
      text: text,
    });
  }
  function handleChangeBook(book) {
    dispatch({
      type: "changed",
      book: book,
    });
  }

  function handleDeleteBook(bookId) {
    dispatch({
      type: "deleted",
      id: bookId,
    });
  }
  function booksReducer(books, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "added": {
        return [
          ...books,
          {
            id: action.id,
            text: action.text,
          },
        ];
      }
      case "changed": {
        return books.map((b) => {
          if (b.id === action.id) {
            return action.book;
          } else {
            return b;
          }
        });
      }
      case "deleted": {
        return books.filter((b) => b.id !== action.id);
      }
      default: {
        throw Error("Unknown action:" + action.type);
      }
    }
  }
  let nextId = 3;
  const initialBooks = [
    { id: 0, text: "Harry Potter" },
    { id: 1, text: "Lord of The Rings" },
    { id: 2, text: "1984" },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <AddBook onAddBook={handleAddBook} />
      <BookList
        books={books}
        onChangeBook={handleChangeBook}
        onDeleteBook={handleDeleteBook}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default MainBook;
```

second component/screen is

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import Book from "./Book"


import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
const BookList = ({ books, onChangeBook, onDeleteBook }) => {
  const navigation=useNavigation();
  return (
    <View>
      {books?.map((book) => {
        <Book book={book} onChange={onChangeBook} onDelete={onDeleteBook} />;
      })}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("AddBook")}><Text>add book</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
export default BookList;
```

and finally third component is

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { useState } from 'react';
const AddBook = ({onAddBook}) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const navigation=useNavigation();
  function handleClick(){
    setText('');
    onAddBook(text);
    navigation.navigate("BookList")
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
      placeholder='add book'
      value={text}
      onChangeText={t=>setText(t)}/>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleClick}>
        <Text>add</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
export default AddBook
```

can  anyone please help for fix this error

I searched web but could not find same error

Answer (score 0):

where do you click the button?

This is the main screen code;

```
import AddBook from "./AddBook";

const App = () => {

  function handleAddBook(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }

  return (
    <View>
        <Text>Code Example</Text>
        <AddBook onAddBook={handleAddBook} />
    </View>
  );

}
```

And there is the AddBook component;

```
const AddBook = ({ onAddBook }) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    function handleClick() {
        setText('');
        onAddBook(text);
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                placeholder='add book'
                value={text}
                onChangeText={t => setText(t)} />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleClick}>
                <Text>add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

And the result is;
[image: Result]

The Question is,
Are you trying to press button from your BookList component's TouchableOpacity? If it is as you can see you don't pass any function to AddBook component from the TouchableOpacity.

```
const BookList = ({ books, onChangeBook, onDeleteBook }) => {
  const navigation=useNavigation();
  return (
    <View>
      {books?.map((book) => {
        <Book book={book} onChange={onChangeBook} onDelete={onDeleteBook} />;
      })}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> /* --> */ navigation.navigate("AddBook")/* <-- */}><Text>add book</Text></TouchableOpacity> 
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: no I'm trying to press button from addbook screen(third component) which  begin wtih const AddBook = ({onAddBook}) => ......and when I press the button that error happens

Comment: I mean, In your first component ->

You use 2 components. 1 is directly to AddBook with function passed. There is no function pass in 2nd one. As you can see when you render booklist component in your first component you can not access that function because you dont pass anything.
return (
    <>
      <AddBook onAddBook={handleAddBook} /> // do you click here?
      <BookList
        books={books}
        onChangeBook={handleChangeBook}
        onDeleteBook={handleDeleteBook}
      /> // or here?
    </>
  );

Comment: <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("AddBook")}> --- Like i said, you dont pass anything to addbook from your booklist component. So if you click you'll get error obviously.
       
This is a part of your booklist's return. ***

These comments are same with my answer. You can read completely.  ***